# Async images for background buttons with kivy

Tags: python, image, button, background, kivy

I need buttons that have as background some async images (from an url, like "https://www.python.org/static/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png", not a file downloaded like "example.png").

I found what to do with normal images (from a file):

`img = Button(text="text", background_normal="image.png")`

I found how to have async images:

`img = AsyncImage(source="https://www.python.org/static/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png")`

(instead of this for files:)

`img = Image(source="image.png")`

But I can not find how to set an async image to the background of the button, please help.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to define your own `AsyncButton`. Here is a simple example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ColorProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

kv = '''
<-AsyncButton>:
    state_image: self.background_normal if self.state == 'normal' else self.background_down
    disabled_image: self.background_disabled_normal if self.state == 'normal' else self.background_disabled_down
    AsyncImage:
        allow_stretch: True
        keep_ratio: False
        source: root.disabled_image if self.disabled else root.state_image
    Label:
        text: root.text
AsyncButton:
    text: 'This is an AsyncButton'
    background_normal: "https://www.python.org/static/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png"
'''


class AsyncButton(ButtonBehavior, FloatLayout):
    text = StringProperty()  # text for Label

    # Properties copied from Button:
    background_color = ColorProperty([1, 1, 1, 1])

    background_normal = StringProperty(
        'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/button')

    background_down = StringProperty(
        'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/button_pressed')

    background_disabled_normal = StringProperty(
        'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/button_disabled')

    background_disabled_down = StringProperty(
        'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/button_disabled_pressed')

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

TestApp().run()
```

This works by creating an `AsyncImage` and just plopping a `Label` on top of it. A `Label` has a transparent background, so the `AsyncImage` shows through. Note that the `Label` used here has no modifiable attributes other than the `text`. If you want more flexibility for the `Label`, you would need to copy the `Properties` that you want from the `Label` class, and reference them in the `Label` in the above `kv`.